# Wavy header with shadow css

Tags: html, css

Could some one bring me on track? How could I make that wave on the bottom of the header?

[image]

This is what I have so far: https://codepen.io/zimex/pen/XaQjZL

```
<header id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
    </div>

    <div class="mobile-wrap">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="user">
          <div class="wrap">
            <span>Hi</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Items</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Are</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Located</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="burger">
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Maybe this link is usefull? [CSS Shapes](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

Comment: Use SVG to achieve something like that

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao how would you add shadow with out using filter?

Answer (score 0):

1) you can use img for this - bad solution but work

2) check http://dev.wavemaker.com/wiki/bin/wmdoc_6.3/CSS

3)

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  background: #eee;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 30px rgba(black, .2);
  background: lighten(#f0f4c3, 10%);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.wave {
  opacity: .4;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  left: 50%;
  background: #0af;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: -250px;
  margin-top: -250px;
  transform-origin: 50% 48%;
  border-radius: 43%;
  animation: drift 3000ms infinite linear;
}

.wave.-three {
  animation: drift 5000ms infinite linear;
}

.wave.-two {
  animation: drift 7000ms infinite linear;
  opacity: .1;
  background: yellow;
}

.box:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(#e8a, 1), rgba(#def, 0) 80%, rgba(white, .5));
  z-index: 11;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  line-height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  letter-spacing: .4em;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(black, .1);
  text-indent: .3em;
}
@keyframes drift {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  from { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

[sample](https://codepen.io/rstacruz/pen/oxJqNv)